# How to resolve libraries <prefix> issues?

Tags: package-management, python, dpkg, dependencies

when i run my code written in Python I got:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I tried

1. `export PYTHONHOME=/usr/lib/Python`  and all other locations where I hoped that libraries or  `dist-packages`  are (since I cannot use Python, I cannot use Python to tell me where the libraries are).
2. [tip from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings) but response for `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv/`is:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

3. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python` but I got this:
   `Processing was halted because there were too many errors.`  - Before this line many errors are written, so just an example:

```
dpkg: error processing package dh-python (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mugshot:
 mugshot depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mugshot (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Setting up python (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of onboard:
 onboard depends on onboard-common (<< 1.4.1-2ubuntu1.1); however:
  Package onboard-common is not configured yet.
 onboard depends on onboard-common (>= 1.4.1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package onboard-common is not configured yet.
 onboard depends on python3 (<< 3.7); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 onboard depends on python3 (>= 3.6~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 onboard depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package onboard (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                        dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of redshift-gtk:
 redshift-gtk depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
```

4. Then I tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but I got same errors as in point 3.
5. (BONUS): Funny thing is that when I write  `pip`  (I used it to install libraries), I got
   `ImportError: No module named site`.

Please, do you have any tips what to try?

PS: Askubuntu seemed to be the best forum to ask, since for me it looks more like ''inside'' problem (I might deleted something?) rather than Python. If not, please, refer me to the right forum.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything I could, the conclusion was: too many dependencies were broken. Therefore, I decided to reinstall my Linux - if I knew how fast re-installisation can be, I wouldn't spend days trying to find the mistake.
[This manual is self-explanatory](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu/), great for "dummies" in Linux. But I learnt a lot.

Main thing I learnt: Do not delete anything you do not know what it is or what it does! :)